# Overlay frames of the animation on top of each other

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

I want to create an animation where the frames will be layered on top of each other. That means that when the first frame will be just the first frame, but the last one should be a mix of all of them.
Is there a way how to do this in the video editor?

Comment: if you render all frames as images, you could then stack all over each other in video editor, yes.

Comment: @Chris If I have cca 100 frames, I cannot do that manually. Is there a way how to automatize that?

Comment: i don't think so. except you now python and the blender-api, should be doable with that.